# I used the C# Stopwatch Class in Unity, but it returns only 00:00:00

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, stopwatch

I want to measure and return the time that passes between the time a user presses the Tab & the Space Button. Unfortunately my Code only returns 00:00:00. This is my code so far.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Debug=UnityEngine.Debug;
public class timer : MonoBehaviour {
    public Stopwatch zeit;
    void Update () {
        zeit = new Stopwatch();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("tab")) {
            zeit.Start();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")){
            TimeSpan ts = zeit.Elapsed;
            zeit.Stop ();
            print(ts);
            zeit.Reset ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new `Stopwatch` every single frame. You want to move `zeit = new Stopwatch();` outside of the `Update` (e.g. in `Start`?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are re-creating the stopwatch when calling update. You can initialize the stopwatch on forehand in the "constructor".

```
public Stopwatch zeit = new StopWatch();
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("tab")) {
        zeit.Start();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")){
        TimeSpan ts = zeit.Elapsed;
        zeit.Stop ();
        print(ts);
        zeit.Reset ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is you always create a new object and set it into **zeit** variable each **Update** function is raised.

**So, you must create that object only one time.**

```
public Stopwatch zeit = new Stopwatch();
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("tab")) {
            zeit.Start();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")){
            TimeSpan ts = zeit.Elapsed;
            zeit.Stop ();
            print(ts);
            zeit.Reset ();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to move your instantiation of `Stopwatch` outside of `Update`. Currently you are recreating your stopwatch every frame.

So move `zeit = new Stopwatch();` outside of `Update`

```
private readonly Stopwatch zeit;

void Start() 
{
    zeit = new Stopwatch();
}

void Update()
{
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You create new Stopwatch each Update method:

```
void Update () {
    zeit = new Stopwatch();
```

Don't do that, instead, try this approach:

```
private readonly Stopwatch _zeit = new Stopwatch();

void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("tab"))
    {
        _zeit.Restart();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")
    {
        print(_zeit.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should stop first.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")){
  //TimeSpan ts = zeit.Elapsed;
  zeit.Stop ();
  //print(ts);
  print(zeit.Elapsed);
  zeit.Reset ();
}
```

Comment: It is not necessary to Stop to get the Elapsed time.